# Lógica para comparar quatro valores e encontrar o menor

Tags: algoritmo, lógica, pseudocódigo

É correto comparar 4 valores dessa forma?

```
Se (A < B && A <  C && A < D){
    Escreva A;
};

Senao Se (B < A && B <  C && B < D){
   Escreva B;
};
Senao Se (C < A && C <  B && C < D){
   Escreva C;
};
Senao Se(D < A && D <  B && D < C){
   Escreva D;
}
Senao{
   Escreva 0;
}
```

Comment: Você disse no comentário de uma resposta que quer pegar o menor valor, certo? E caso houver dois valores menores iguais, por exemplo, **A=0**, B=1, **C=0** e D=3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repare que da forma que você implementou é possível precisar de mais de três comparações. É possível encontrar mínimo de quatro valores com apenas três comparações em qualquer circunstância (ou seja, com melhor desempenho), isso de várias maneiras.

Por exemplo, pode-se encontrar o mínimo "M1" de "A" e "B" (`M1=( A<B ? A : B );`), depois encontrar o mínimo "N" de "C" e "M" (`M2=( C<M1 ? C : M1 );`) e finalmente retornar o mínimo de "D" e "M2" (`return( D<M2 ? D : M2 );`).

Outra forma (que pode ser melhor se puder paralelizar) é encontrar o mínimo "M" de "A" e "B" (`M=( A<B ? A : B );`) e paralelamente encontrar o mínimo "N" de "C" e "D" (`N=( C<D ? C : D );`), então é só retornar o mínimo de "M" e "N" (`return( M<N ? M : N );`).

Se quiser implementar este segundo sem usar temporários "M" e "N", pode-se usar a seguinte penca de comparações que utiliza o mesmo raciocínio, mas talvez não seja tão bem otimizado mesmo por bons compiladores.

```
if( A<B ){
    if( C<D ) return( A<C ? A : C );
    else return( A<D ? A : D );
}
else {
    if( C<D ) return( B<C ? B : C );
    else return( B<D ? B : D );
}
```

Se quiser generalizar o problema para encontra o mínimo de "n" números "a[0], a[1], ..., a[n-1]", pode-se de várias formas calcular o mínimo deles com "n-1" comparações. Uma delas é a seguinte, que é generalização do primeiro algoritmo citado.

```
T = a[0] ;
for( i=1 ; i<n ; i=i+1 ){
    if( T>a[i] ) T = a[i] ;
}
return T ;
```

Já a generalização do segundo requer recursão, coisa que somente vale a pena se der para compilar de forma otimizada (sem precisar de empilhamento) e neste caso é bom que há meios de se calcular paralelamente.

Isso se faz encontrando o mínimo "M" da primeira metade dos números, o mínimo "N" da segunda metade e depois retornar o mínimo de "M" e "N", onde a parada da recursão é a sequência de tamanho um, que aí o único número trabalhado é o mínimo.

Alguma dúvida?

Answer (score 5):

Pode otimizar e acho que tem um erro:

```
Se (A < B && A < C && A < D) {
    Escreva A;
} Senao Se (B < C && B < D) {
   Escreva B;
} Senao Se (C < D) {
   Escreva C;
} Senao {
   Escreva D;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/GreatherThree.pd).

Se `A` não é menor que os outros 3 não tem mais porque verificá-lo. Depois o mesmo com `B`, e finalmente com `C`. Se nenhum é menor que `D` então `D` é o menor. Não entendi porque poderia resultar em 0. Só se tinha algum requisito não descrito.

Comment: Entendi. O zero é so se caso desse erro do jeito que eu tava comparando.

Comment: Valeu Mano.....

Answer (score 3):

Isso até funciona, se os valores forem todos diferentes (se tiver dois ou mais valores iguais, dará errado). Entretanto, o número de verificações dentro dos `Se`s vai crescer de maneira insustentável quanto mais variáveis você tiver, pois se você tiver ***N*** variáveis, precisará de ***N² - N*** testes com operadores relacionais.

A abordagem do Maniero reduz o número de verificações pela metade (***(N² - N) / 2***), mas existe uma abordagem simples que usa apenas ***N - 1*** verificações:

```
MenorValor := A
Se (B < MenorValor) MenorValor := B;
Se (C < MenorValor) MenorValor := C;
Se (D < MenorValor) MenorValor := D;
Escreva MenorValor;
```

Comment: Então, Victor. O problema é que eu vou comparar 4 métodos. O que retornar o menor valor eu irei usá-lo. Não vejo uma maneira de fazer isso usando essa lógica.

Comment: @Hacker O que você quer dizer por "*comparar 4 métodos*"? Se A, B, C e D são variáveis, você simplesmente usa isso. Se forem chamadas a funções ou procedimentos, você salva o resultado de cada uma em uma variável e faz isso (o que também impede que elas sejam executadas mais do que uma vez). Qual é o impedimento?